# trouble with symbols while expressing operational semantics

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I  am trying to write some inference rules but I'm not able to understand the meaning of the symbols generally used to write them.

For example: 
I have written the following rule for a some type-expression:

```
 class(r) ∈ t,  \there_exists v ⊢ r ∈ type(v)
-------------------------------------------------------------
 Γ, m:n -> r ⊢ n:(Γ, r, {}) <-  r
```

`m` is a declaration where `n` is replaced by `r`.

(if the `r` in expression belongs to `t` (type-expression) and there exists a `v` such that `r` belongs to the type of `v`).

May be my equation is completely wrong.
At least somebody please explain the meaning of `⊢` and `:` operator.
Also in the Benjamin Pierce's book, he calls `Γ` as typing-context. 
Can somebody explain its meaning with an example (I'd appreciate if the example is in  Haskell or Lisp or C++)

Thanks

PS: This is not a homework.

Comment: I like the two answers below. I'll just add that the meaning of ⊢ and Γ here are broader conventions than the specific operational-semantics-for-typed-languages that you're discussing here. You can think of ⊢ like a comma that separates what's supplied and what can be gotten from it. And capital Greek letters are generally used here for sets. You might see a deduction system for a logic stated in those terms. You might also see some of this notation used to give operational semantics without types, and say, small \rho used on the lhs of ⊢ to represent the global state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a high level, the notation is simple: given that the conditions above the lines are held, the expression below the line is true.

Γ is a typing context--that is, it is a set of pairs of variables and types. These pairs map variables to types. The ⊢ just means "in the context". The colon just combines a variable with a type--it's like `::` in Haskell or `:` in Scala or Ocaml. So something like `Γ ⊢ x:σ` means that "in context Γ, x has type σ". Something like `Γ,x:σ` means the context made up of `Γ` and `x:σ`.

Essentially, the context represents all the types the other variables have. So `x:σ ∈ Γ` means that `x` has type `σ` in `Γ`, which lets you trivially resolve that `Γ ⊢ x:σ`. All this is saying is that if `x` is bound to some type in a context, it has that type in that context.

You can think of the typing context as all the type information from the "outside". So the trivial statement in the above paragraph basically tells you that if you see an `x` and `x` already has type `σ`, you can infer that `x` has type `σ`. Not very interesting, but very important!

You could write this rule out as:

```
x:σ ∈ Γ
-------
Γ ⊢ x:σ
```

If only we had LaTeX :P. I guess we're not as cool as math.se or cstheory.se.

Here is a slightly more complicated example. Essentially, we want to encode how application works in the simply typed lambda calculus. It's actually very simple: given a function `f` of type `τ → τ'` and a value `x` of type `τ` then `f x` has type `τ'`. In Haskell, this would look like applying `f :: Int -> Bool` on `x :: Int`. It's pretty clear that `f x :: Bool`. So let's write this out.

The condition (the top bit) is that, in some context, `f` has a type `τ → τ'`: `Γ ⊢ f:τ → τ'`. Also, in that same context, `x` has type `τ`: `Γ ⊢ x:τ`. Put together, we get: `Γ ⊢ f:τ → τ' Γ ⊢ x:τ`.

Now on to the bottom bit. Given these two types, what do we know? We know the type of the application `f x` *but only in the same context*. (This is why `Γ` matters.) So we get: `Γ ⊢ f x:τ'`.

And now, putting it all together, we have:

```
Γ ⊢ f:τ → τ' Γ ⊢ x:τ 
--------------------
     Γ ⊢ f x:τ'
```

Seeing the StackOverflow syntax highlighter struggle with that last example is amusing. I wonder which language it thinks that's in.

Answer (score 3):

The `Γ` (if anyone knows how to embed LaTeX please leave a comment or edit the comment) is a symbol for the typing context: you can view it as a map between an expression and it's type.

For example, let's take two contexts:

- `Γ0` the empty map and
- `Γ1 = Γ0, x:Int` the previous one enriched with a type information saying that `x` has type `Int`. Thus, `:` here stands for type assignment.

Now, in the empty context (`Γ0`) there is no way to type the expression `x + x` because you don't know the type of `x` (it is not stored in the map). However, in the other context we have a type for `x` (that is `Int`) so we can say that `x + x` has type `Int`.

Formally, we have used a rule like this one:

```
  x : σ ∈ Γ
______________
 Γ ⊢ x + x: σ
```

Observe that `:` stands for `::` in Haskell. And `A ⊢ B` is to be read as "in the context of `A` `B` holds.

PS: I had a course about Type Systems, you can find some of the materials [here](http://elf.cs.pub.ro/tsfp/Curs.zip) (and you may look at Typed_Lambda_Calculus.pdf).

Comment: You can't embed LaTeX in StackOverflow posts (as far as I know). But you can just use an actual Γ.

Comment: Also, I'm going to take a class on this next semester, and my professor is going to be from Romania. Just a fun coincidence. I think he even attended the same university as the one you linked to :).

Comment: George Necula. I haven't met him yet, but he seems really cool.

Comment: Cool. I've heard about him a little, you'll enjoy his classes.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture notes.